# Is MySQL Clustering a viable option for a DB expecting 5TB of data in 5 years?

Tags: cluster, mysql-cluster

We plan to implement MySQL Clustering.The database should support 5 years of data and expected data/year is 1TB.

When we created a test enviornment with the DB size as 200GB, NDB Cluster took more than 2 hours to restart.

Is MySQL Clustering a viable option for an application that expects 5TB of data in 5 years, if yes, could you please guide on the suggested architecture and configuration for such a setup.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with the data in MySQL? I have not used MySQL clustering in several years, due to the same problem you are running into.

Have you considered something else for the task like Cassandra for your needs? Much easier to handle large amounts of data and easily able to scale servers to support your workload.